# How to check if a page is category or product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to use is_category in `woocommerce.php` which is not working. I want to print the title according the page.

IF a page is category page then will print `woocommerce_page_title()` and if a page is product then should print `the_title()`.

And the code I am using in `woocommerce.php` is:

```
<?php if(is_category()){ ?>                       
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1> 
<?php }
else{
    the_title();
}
?>
```

But in every case it is printing `the_title()` . I think `is_category()` is not working for woocommerce.

Or Can any one tell how woocommerce do it to print category and product title?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you should use

```
is_product_category()
```

instead of

```
is_category()
```

Comment: Awesome.. you made it so easy..I have wasted my too much time in finding alternative of above question.. So thankyou!

Comment: Here are the docs on all conditional tags - http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score 1):

More Concisely

```
if( is_product_category( array( 5, 10, 891 ) ) ) {

// do something for product categories with ID = 5 or 10 or 891


} elseif( is_product_category( 'snowboards' ) ) {
// do something only for product categories with slug or title "snowboards"

} else {

// do something else for other pages

}
```

As product categories are taxonomies. So, here is the list of WordPress native conditional tags we can use as well:

```
is_tax( 'product_cat' ) – it is an equivalent to is_product_category(),
is_tax( 'product_cat', $category ) – the same story…
```

This is the example, similar to above:

```
if( is_tax( 'product_cat', array( 5, 10, 891 ) ) ) {

} elseif( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'snowboards' ) ) {

} else {

}
```

The reasonable question is – “What is the difference?”

There is no difference, the function is_product_category() is just a wrapper for is_tax( 'product_cat' ).

Answer (score -4):

Try creating a `archive-product.php` file within the theme templates.

I usually copy the one that is in the `woocommerce` folder and add a span with "test" text to the one I create so I can see it's working.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: This is adding a template, not checking if a page is a category page in the same template. That's why it's not an answer.